# how do I calculate population weighted average in a panel data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panel dataset with ~1600 rows and columns of state, year, population, variable, and neighbors. Here is a pseudo sample:

| state | year | population | variable | neighbors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AL | 1990 | 10 | 0.023 | FL,GA,TN |
| FL | 1990 | 20 | 0.5 | AL,GA |
| GA | 1990 | 30 | 0.01 | NC,SC,TN,FL,AL |
| TN | 1990 | 25 | 0.3 | AL,AK,GA,KT,MI,MO,VA |

I want to calculate a new column, variable_weighted, as the population weighted mean of variable based on the neighboring states. For instance, the first row should be:
(20x0.5+30x0.01+25*0.3)/(20+30+25). Note that the population varies by year. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You will need to ad a bit more data, the calculation you want and expected output from this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may find a sleeker or more efficient approach, but this can be done by applying a custom function. I'm assuming that you have records for every state in every year that you have. Otherwise, this will give an error.
First, this will be easier if state and year are the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['AL', 'FL', 'GA', 'TD'],
                   'year': [1990, 1990, 1990, 1990],
                   'population': [10, 20, 30, 25],
                   'variable': [.023, .5, .01, .3],
                   'neighbors': ['FL,GA,TN', 'AL,GA', 'NC,SC,TN,FL,AL',
                                 'AL,AK,GA,KT,MI,MO,VA']
                   })

df = df.set_index(['state', 'year'])
```

We're going to apply a function to the dataframe that takes a row (which is a pandas series) as input. Inside the function, we will split the comma-separated string of states into a list of states. Then we will filter the dataframe (with `.loc[]`) for the state/year combos we want, in the format of a pandas `MultiIndex` object. Then once the dataframe is filtered, calculate the weighted average with `np.average`.

```
def neighbors_avg(row):
    neighbors_list = row['neighbors'].split(',')
    neighbors_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([neighbors_list, [row.name[1]]])
    neighbors = df.loc[neighbors_index]
    return np.average(neighbors['variable'], weights = neighbors['population'])

df['neighbors_avg'] = df.apply(neighbors_avg, axis = 1)
```

We need `axis = 1` to apply the function to each row, by default it would be each column.

Earlier we made `'state', 'year'` the index. If you want to undo that afterward, use `df = df.reset_index()`.